# find max between two indices of unsorted array in O(1) time

Tags: arrays, search

In an un sorted array, (we can pre-process this array). How can we answer the following query in O(1) time?     Find the maximum from index i to j

**Edit:** The preprocessing can take O(n) time and O(n) order of extra memory, so that the query which comes too often is answered in O(1) time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem (called the Range Minimum Query problem) is solved (O(n) preprocessing, O(1) queries). From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Minimum_Query):

> It is known that a O(n)-time preprocessing is sufficient to answer subsequent queries in O(1) time. The space of the resulting scheme is actually very small, namely O(n) bits (see Fischer & Heun (2007)).

The RMQ problem is exactly equivalent to your problem (just replace "minimum" with "maximum"). See http://wcipeg.com/wiki/RMQ#Cartesian_trees for a sketch of the algorithm and a proof of its correctness and memory/time guarantees.

Also see this [TopCoder tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Range_Minimum_Query_%28RMQ%29) for an overview of the different options available to solve this problem in essentially increasing order of implementation complexity.

Answer (score 1):

No memory constraint or preprocessing constraint? Just make an O(n<sup>2</sup>) table with every possible answer (i.e. one entry for each possible value of `i` and `j`). This table can be made naïvely in O(n<sup>3</sup>) time, and can be brought down to O(n<sup>2</sup>) very easily by computing the maximum incrementally.

Comment: Best to mention these kinds of limitations when you ask the question :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You will either need to walk over the array to find maximum value which will take O(n), or you will need to precompute by either sorting the array (more expensive than O(n)) or determining the maximum for all possible ranges which will is both more expensive than O(n) and will require way too much memory.

Comment: Well, no, I think that this is a very simplistic way of looking at the problem. Why is it impossible? Don't present a false dichotomy -- you need a real proof that it is not possible.

Comment: Giving a real proof requires a bit of CS theory. This particular problem should be covered in any CS class that touches algorithm design and/or complexity analysis.

Comment: There is actually one theoretical solution here: if you have the same number of CPUs as you have elements in the array slice you are looking at you can do a do a scan over all elements in parallel to find the maximum. In practice you are likely to have more elements than CPUs, and the overhead of communication is likely to be much higher than any theoretical benefits of this approach which makes this unworkable.

Comment: This particular problem turns out to be not-so-easy given the new constraints. The O(n) preprocessing solution was discovered in *2007* -- given that most "easy" CS complexity-theory problems were solved in the 70s and 80s, this indicates that the problem is not easy. I doubt that the proof is covered in an intro CS theory course ;)

Answer (score -1):

Unless your preprocessing can be greater than O(1), not possible.  What's wrong with sorting it?  That's only O(n*log(n)) (or a maximum O(n) if radix sorting is allowed).

Comment: Sorting totally destroys the meaning of the problem -- we're trying to find the maximum from indices `i` to `j`, and sorting would make those queries meaningless.

Comment: Right, but without some non-constant-time preprocessing, it's not possible.  Sorting is as good enough an operation as any other.

Comment: How are you going to answer the queries with a sorted array?

Comment: Since it was edited: make an array of size n, containing the numbers 0 to n-1 in increasing order.  Sort that with your first array's comparison functions in n*log(n) time.  Interpret the new array as indices.  Find your answer in O(1).

Comment: Maybe I'm tired, but I don't see how you can get the maximum of an arbitrary range in O(1) using only a sorted index array. Say I have `a = [4,2,7,1,8,2,3,6,0,1,7,3,0,2,9]`, in which case I have the sorted index array `[8, 12, 3, 9, 1, 5, 13, 6, 11, 0, 7, 2, 10, 4, 14]`. What's `max(a[5..9])`?

Comment: @nneonneo is correct in saying that sorting would destroy the meaning of the problem